# Converting from console applications to GUI

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I programmed a human detector using HOG by training an SVM in Visual Studio 2010 using OpenCV. Now im trying to make a User Interface for the same. It only works for the first time and the console opens every time i execute the code. I dont want the console to be shown as im showing all the inputs and outputs in the windows form. How can I change the code so that it detects as long as i want. Basically after the control is left from the form it doesnt come back to the form. how can i bring the control back to the main form once i have finished detecting it for an input image???? Any help would be appreciated. I need to submit my project by the end of the month plzzz help....

Answer (score 0):

The structure and control flow of a GUI are quite different from a console program. First find a tutorial for creating a basic GUI program with whatever library you are using (Win32, MFC, WPF, Qt...?). Then copy, paste and adapt pieces of your console code into event handlers in the GUI framework.

Comment: I am using CLR project in visual c++ to create the GUI